# Android Play Audio Sequentially

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a list of audio file resource Ids `resIds` and I want to loop through this list and play the audios sequentially one after the other. How could I do that?

I am using android studio and kotlin.

Note: The following code playes all the audio files at once, I want to play them sequentially.

```
for(id in resIds){
    MediaPlayer.create(activity, id).start()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [setOnCompletionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)) - play first audio file and when callback fire then play next one

Comment: A straight forward implementation of this is a recursive call. Is it possible to do this with simple iteration? Is playing a bunch of clips one after another such a complex task in android?